# How to load a string input(groovy script) using GroovyScriptEngine from Java

Tags: java, string, groovy

I have a string input, which is a groovy script, which contains one or more methods like :

```
def printHello()
{
    println("Inside printHello()")
}

def setData(String str)
{  
    println("Incoming data : " + str)
}
```

This is in a string format, which is my input.

From a Java program, I want to load this string by using GroovyScriptEngine.

I am able to load and invoke the above methods by using GroovyClassLoader successfully.

```
new GroovyClassLoader().parseClass(scriptStr)
```

Unfortunately, by using **GroovyScriptEngine**, I cannot able to load the string.

I stored this string input into a temporary groovy file and tried to load.
It is working.

But my intention is to load a string input directly by using GroovyScriptEngine.

Is there any way to load groovy script content as string input to the GroovyScriptEngine instead of using a file path?

Please help me on this...

Note : This is for my comparison study between GroovyClassLoader and GroovyScriptEngine.

Answer (score 0):

GroovyClassLoader can load the class directly but cannot handle it dependency. 
GroovyScriptEngine can only load the script but not the class. However, it can handles class dependency and hot reloading.

You can find the detail here. 
http://groovy-lang.org/integrating.html